# What is the consistency strength of the following pattern of failure of the continuum hypothesis?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, continuum-hypothesis

> What is the least theory in which the following sentence is proved?

> $ \exists M: M\text { is CTM(ZFC+ GCH)} \land \forall \kappa \in Card^M (\kappa > 1 \implies \\\exists N: N \text { is CTM(ZFC) } \land  Card^N=Card^M \land \operatorname\neg \operatorname {CH}^N(\kappa))$

Where $Card^S=\{\kappa : S \models \exists x \, (\kappa=|x|)\}$

$\operatorname {CH}(\kappa) \iff \not \exists \lambda: \kappa < \lambda < 2^\kappa$

"$\operatorname {CH}^N..$" is the relativization of all quantifiers in the open expansion of "$\operatorname {CH}..$" by "$\in N$".

In English: There exists a countable transitive model $M$ of ZFC +GCH such that for every $M$-cardinal $\kappa$ (bigger than 1) there is a countable transitive model $N$ of ZFC such that the set of all $N$-cardinals is the set of all $M$-cardinals (so  existence of injections between cardinals in both models is preserved), and such that $\kappa$ violate the continuum hypothesis in $N$.

Comment: Doesn't the standard forcing argument show that this holds as soon as there is some CTM of ZFC?

Comment: @Wojowu, I'm not sure of that. This is my guess, that's why I asked this question. So, if this is correct then it is ZFC+ there is some CTM of ZFC? Or is it something more than that?

Comment: It should be literally just ZFC+there is some CTM of ZFC. Then you should be able to make GCH fail at $\kappa$ by adding more than $\kappa$ reals to the model, and this should moreover not change any cardinals. The condition on injections is equivalent to that, I don't know why you added it separately. I am not that well-versed in forcing so I will let someone more knowledgeable confirm all this and post an answer.

Comment: @Wojowu, you mean the condition on injections is redundant?

Comment: Yes.  For two ordinals $\gamma,\lambda$ there is an injection between them iff it's not the case $\gamma\geq\kappa>\lambda$ for some cardinal $\kappa$. If the cardinals are the same in $M,N$, then obviously the corresponding conditions are equivalent.

Comment: I believe that in general, if $A$ is class of sentences expressible in the language of set theory that is consistent relative to $\mathsf{ZFC}$, then the theory $\mathsf{ZFC} + \exists M[M \models \mathsf{ZFC} \wedge \forall \sigma \in A[M \models \sigma]]$ is either inconsistent or equiconsistent to $\mathsf{ZFC} +  \exists M[M \models \mathsf{ZFC}]$ (under the base theory $\mathsf{ZFC}$). I'm not sure though.

Comment: @Wojowu, Ok, I agree. I've deleted that condition.

Comment: This was shown by Cohen. Simply blow up the continuum up above $\kappa^+$ by adding Cohen reals. If you want to preserve CH below $\lambda$, for whatever $\lambda<\kappa$, since we assume GCH in $M$, just add $\lambda^+$-Cohen reals to blow $2^{\lambda^+}$ to be above $\kappa^+$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, what's the consistency strength of that? Is it ZFC + there is a CTM of ZFC?

Comment: You are literally requiring a CTM, so, yes. But it's just Cohen/Cohen-style forcing. Nothing more than that.